# SQL Insert statement with multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

This seems really trivial, but for the life of me I cannot understand why this is not working. Any ideas would be great!

```
USE [ACCTQA]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[glacct]
           ([Company]
           ,[Account]
           ,[Description])
     VALUES
 ('E096','191802','INVESTMENT IN SUBS')
,('E096','320007','COMMON STOCK')
,('E096','330013','SURPLUS')
,('E096','340003','RETAINED EARNINGS')
,('E096','690876','LIAB & CASUALTY INS')
,('E096','710000','BONDS - AGENCY BILL')
,('E096','710001','COMM. P&C - AGENCY BILL')
,('E096','710002','EMPL BENEFITS-AGENCY BILL')
```

ERROR MSG:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Comment: Any error message would be great

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using? It works for SQL Server 2008 and above http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd272

Comment: if you use SQL Server CE, than it doesn't support bulk insert as I know

Comment: `[dbo].[glacct]` table structure and error message!!!

Comment: Are you getting a PK violation?

Comment: The database is on SQL 2005. All columns are char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
USE [ACCTQA]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[glacct]
           ([Company]
           ,[Account]
           ,[Description])
SELECT * FROM (   
SELECT 'E096','191802','INVESTMENT IN SUBS' UNION ALL
SELECT 'E096','320007','COMMON STOCK' UNION ALL
SELECT 'E096','330013','SURPLUS' UNION ALL
SELECT 'E096','340003','RETAINED EARNINGS'
.....)
```

I'm guessing your version is not accepting multiple values like this, so you have to use a select statement(INSERT FROM SELECT) to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Your query won't work if you are using SQL Server 2005 or below. On those version you have to try like

```
INSERT INTO glacct
  ([Company],[Account],[Description]) 
SELECT 'E096','191802','INVESTMENT IN SUBS'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E096','320007','COMMON STOCK'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E096','330013','SURPLUS'
```

Your query will work on SQL Server 2008 and above,.

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd272)**

Comment: That's my answer.. are you serious?

Comment: This only inserted the first 366 rows. No errors, states that query executed successfully?

Answer (score 0):

It did the trick...

```
CREATE TABLE #glacct (Company VARCHAR(100),
                        Account INT,
                    Description VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[#glacct]
           ([Company],
            [Account],
            [Description])
     VALUES
('E096','191802','INVESTMENT IN SUBS'),
('E096','320007','COMMON STOCK'),
('E096','330013','SURPLUS'),
('E096','340003','RETAINED EARNINGS'),
('E096','690876','LIAB & CASUALTY INS'),
('E096','710000','BONDS - AGENCY BILL'),
('E096','710001','COMM. P&C - AGENCY BILL'),
('E096','710002','EMPL BENEFITS-AGENCY BILL')
```

PS: Done with SQLServer 2014 ...